# CSS displaying as typed text in pug

Tags: html, css, express, pug

I'm doing a web development course where we are making this project using pug/express and everything was working perfectly, Then after some time, the CSS code started to display as text, even in the developer tool it is showing #text under the style tag. The code and everything is correct and CSS is also showing when I attach it with an HTML file and go live(VS CODE extension) but it's only showing as text when I run it with pug/express using nodemon.
Here's the photo. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpT2q.png)

javaScript code

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const port = 8000;
    
// EXPRESS SPECIFIC STUFF
app.use('../static', express.static('static')) // For serving static files
app.use(express.urlencoded()) 
    
// PUG SPECIFIC STUFF
app.set('view engine', 'pug') // Set the template engine as pug
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')) // Set the views directory
   
// ENDPOINTS
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const params = {}
  res.status(200).render('index.pug', params);
})
    
// START THE SERVER
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`The application started successfully on port ${port}`);
});
```

Pug code

```js
//- index.pug
    doctype html
    html
      head
        styles
           include ../static/style.css
      body
        nav#navbar
         ul 
          li #[a(href="/") Home] 
          li #[a(href="/") About]
          li #[a(href="/") Servives] 
          li #[a(href="/") Class info] 
          li #[a(href="/") Contact Us]  
      
      section#introsection 
        div  Welcome to the best Dance Academy in Delhi 
        div  Eat Sleep Dance Repeat 
      section#missonsection 
        h2 Our Mission
        div.card
            h3 Dance Perfection
        div.card
            h3 Dance the way you like    
        div.card
            h3 Dance bla bla    
      section#sponsorssection 
        h2 Our Sponsors     
      footer#footer 
        | our footer here 
        script
          include ../static/index.js
```

CSS code

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comforter+Brush&family=Roboto+Slab:wght@100&display=swap'); 
    
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
} 
    
/* Navigation bar  */
#navbar{
  font-family: 'Comforter Brush', cursive;
  background-color: rgb(218, 84, 84);
  padding: 18px 14px ;
}

#navbar ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

#navbar li{
  list-style: none;
}

#navbar li a{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white; 
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 13px 30px;
}

#navbar li a:hover{
  color: black;
}
    
/* Intro Section */
#introsection{
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;   
  align-items: center;
  height: 425px;
  background-color: red;
  background:url("/static/bg.jpg") center/cover  no-repeat;
}
    
/* Misson Section */
#missionsection{
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  width: 67%;
  background-color: rgb(44, 44, 30);
}
    
.card{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid bloack;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 23px 20px;
  height: 210px;
}
    
.card h3{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 12px;
}
    
/* Sponsor section */
#sponsorssection{
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(163, 163, 160);
}

#sponsorssection h2{
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 12px ;
}
    
/* footer */
#footer{
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself.

Comment: I've added the necessary code.

Comment: `styles` isn't an HTML element. Use `style` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If your css is already in a file `../static/styles.css`, where `../static` is the folder mapped for static files and thus the file is publicly available, you can use a `<link>` instead:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css")
  body
    blah blah blah
```

Similarly, if your script file is in the same location, you can include it as:

```
script(src="/index.js")
```

If you are very new to Pug, at your browser, view source to inspect the Html generated to understand the relationship between Pug syntax and actual Html.

Comment: doesn't work...

Comment: @MohdAfnanAlam What does the source in your browser (Ctrl-U) look like? Does going to localhost:8000/styles.css give you your css file contents? I just noticed you have a script file at the end. Can similarly do `script(src="/index.js")` in Pug, which generates `<script src="/index.js"></script>`.